# ERLANG wait() and blocking

Tags: erlang, wait

Does the following function block on its running core?

```erlang
wait(Sec) -> 
   receive
   after (1000 * Sec) -> ok
end.
```

A great answer will detail the internal working of Erlang and/or the CPU.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The process which executes that code *will* block, the scheduler which runs that process currently *will not* block. The code you posted is equal to a yield, but with a timeout.

The Erlang VM scheduler for that core will continue to execute other processes until that timeout fires and that process will be scheduled for execution again.

Comment: Is there an erlang equivalent of NodeJS's `setTimeout`? It's non-blocking for the current thread

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: You either block on a receive right now (with or without timeout), or you don't. You can schedule work in between your `receive` calls by setting the timeout to `0`. This essentially means checking your inbox, and continuing work if it is empty. You can also schedule more advanced checks using for example [`send_after/3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#send_after-3).

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: this will block only current (lightweight) process, and will not block all VM. For more details you must read about erlang scheduler. Nice description comes from book "Concurent Programming" by Francesco Cesarini and Simon Thompson.

> ...snip...
>   When a process is dispatched, it is assigned a number of reductions†
>   it is allowed to execute, a number which is reduced for every
>   operation executed. As soon as the process enters a receive clause
>   where none of the messages matches or its reduction count reaches
>   zero, it is preempted. As long as BIFs are not being executed, this
>   strategy results in a fair (but not equal) allocation of execution
>   time among the processes.
>   ...snip...

Answer (score 1):

nothing Erlang-specific, pretty classical problem: timeouts can only happen on a system clock interrupt. Same answer as above: that process is blocked waiting for the clock interrupt, everything else is working just fine.

There is another discussion about the actual time that process is going to wait which is not that precise exactly because it depends on the clock period (and that's system dependent) but that's another topic.