# calling a blocking library in node.js vs erlang vm

Tags: node.js, erlang, blocking, nonblocking

In node.js, if my thread calls a blocking library, it can't accept any more requests until it gets back a response from the library. Is this the same situation with the Erlang virtual machine - i.e., can other processes keep accepting requests if one of the processes makes a call to a blocking library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Erlang, a process might block, but the Erlang scheduler will *not* block. Other processes will continue to be executed / given time by the scheduler. There are some calls like `erlang:now` that block all for a very short time, but there are non-blocking alternatives. If I recall correctly, Ericson is working hard to remove all blocking stuff from the Erlang VM. and most blocks are subtle edge-cases. For example: in R16, the last release, they fixed blocking hot-code upgrades.

See also [ERLANG wait() and blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981938/erlang-wait-and-blocking)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can accepting requests with one process and make calls to blocking library with other.
What do you want to achieve? If it's something like: "first client send data to server, and waits for answer, but server does not blocking and can accept request from others clients", you can do it something like this (example with gen_server behaviour):

```
handle_call(ClientRequest, From, State) ->
    %% make call to blocking library
    %% for the simplicity use spawn_link
    MyPid = self(),
    _Pid = spawn_link(fun() -> %% blocking data processing
                           ...
                           Result = ...
                           %% send reply back to server.
                           %% From -- using for answer to clients
                           gen_server:cast(MyPid, {reply, From, Result})
                       end)
    %% tell client wait for answer.
    {noreply, State}.

handle_cast({reply, To, Data}, State) ->
    %% send reply back to client
    gen_serve:reply(To, Data),
    {noreply, State}.
```

Comment: I wanted to verify that in case I have to make a call to a blocking library, it will only affect that process, and not halt the entire server. The most repeated warning in node.js resources is to take extreme caution to not call a blocking library/function, or it will halt your entire server. If this is not the case in Erlang, and the server can keep interacting with clients, this is a big point in Erlang's favor over node.js

Comment: The important aspect here is that is the central point of Erlang: processes can be preempted if they were to block. Node.js is extremely cooperative, and hence it needs you to explicitly avoid blocking. Great care has been taken to make sure the Erlang VM stays responsive even if a process  is not calling a function which would block, or if a process takes too long to run a given process on the cores.